# Excel VBA 'If Then Else' Statement fails

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm new to SO, so please forgive any nuances I don't include in my question. I've come to you guys for help with some coding i'm writing in Excel VBA. I have a cell that is the sum of a range of cells which are filled with decimals and formatted as percents (e.g. Cell C4 = 40.00%, C4 actual value = 0.4). in my code I have an I/T statement that reads as follows:

```
If PC.Range("c16").Value = 1 Then

' do a bunch of stuff ' 

Else:

MsgBox "Percentages don't add to 100%."
```

The problem I have is, the order of that range of cells' values sometimes triggers the code to enter into the Else part of the code, even though the cell DOES = 1. Has anyone seen this or can anyone help? I can provide other info if necessary and I can even send the Excel code in its entirety if needed.

Thank you all in advance and I look forward to learning!

Chris

Comment: Is it a floating point number?  I'd try `Debug.Print TypeName(PC.Range("c16").Value)` to make sure it isn't getting to you as a double.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your code, try something like this:

```
Dim dDebug as Double

dDebug = PC.Range("C16").Value

msgbox dDebug ' or use Debug.Print if you have the immediate window showing

If PC.Range("c16").Value = 1 Then

' do a bunch of stuff ' 

Else ' Note that I have removed the colon on the else given that it is not needed.
    MsgBox "Percentages don't add to 100%."
```

This should show you exactly the value that your code is seeing. Without seeing the workbook you are working with, I would wager that what is happening is it looks like the value is 1, but it is actually being rounded up.

If this isn't the case, my next bet would be that PC isn't being set properly, and the wrong value is being checked.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I actually have: 

    Debug.Print PC.Range("c16").

Value which prints the value of the cell, and it printed up to 4 decimals in the Test window. The catch is that rearranging the values of the percentages sometimes fixes the issue.

Comment: In that case there is likely some kind of rounding happening when it is adding together your numbers. Without seeing your file it is hard to pinpoint where or how this is happening. You may want to try "CDec(PC.Range("C16").Value) = 1" to ensure that the number is staying as a decimal number during the comparison. The code shouldnt be rounding it, but it doesn't hurt to be certain. Otherwise, something else is happening within your worksheet.

Comment: Wow thanks Brandon! that seems to have fixed it! That's amazing!

Comment: No problem at all, I am glad I could help! I would suggest reading up on Type Conversions if you do a lot of comparisons. You may find value in the Format() function as well. When used together you can ensure your comparisons are running properly each time. Here is the MSDN page for conversions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx.

Comment: @BrandonBarney you don't need to assign a variable to `PC.Range("C16").Value` to view it in `MsgBox`, you could use `Msgbox PC.Range("C16").Value`

Comment: @Shai I only did that to see if there was anything going on as far as type coercion. Debug.printing the range wouldon't allow me to explicitly determine what kind of value it was. I know it rarely makes a difference, but I wanted to rule out the value being coerced into a round number.